# Не отображаются символы текста, которые были получены с помощью скрапинга с cheerio (Node JS)

Tags: node.js

Все так, как и в заголовке написано. Выходят какие то кракозябры типо '�'. Как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    app.get('/rplTopScores', (req, res) => {
        res.send(rplTopScores);
    });

await axios('https://www.sport-express.ru/football/L/russia/premier/2022-2023/statistics/bombardiers/') // rplTopScores
    .then(response => response.data)
    .then(response => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(response);

        $('table.se19-table-statistics tr').each((i, element) => {
            rplTopScores.push({
                player: $(element).find('.se19-table-statistics__td--name a').text()
            });
            console.log($(element).find('.se19-table-statistics__td--name a').text());
        });
        
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Попробуй cheerio.load(response, { decodeEntities: false })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import * as cheerio from 'cheerio';
import iconv from 'iconv-lite';

const res = await fetch(
  'https://www.sport-express.ru/football/L/russia/premier/2022-2023/statistics/bombardiers/'
);

const charset = (res.headers.get('content-type') ?? '')
  .split(/\s*;\s*/).find(
    (/** @type {string} */ x) => x.startsWith('charset')
  )?.replace(/charset=/, '');

const buf = await res.arrayBuffer();
const html = iconv.decode(
  Buffer.from(buf),
  charset || 'windows-1251'
);

const $ = cheerio.load(html);

$('table.se19-table-statistics tr').each((i, element) => {
  const text = $(element).find('.se19-table-statistics__td--name a').text();
  console.log(text);
});
```

```bash
$ node 52863124.js 

Квинси Промес
Эдуард Сперцян
Кристиан Нобоа
Филипе Силва Малком
Владимир Сычевой
Тимур Сулейманов
Маркус Вендел
Николай Комличенко
Хорхе Карраскаль
Хесус Мануэль Медина
Федор Чалов
Дмитрий Полоз
...
```

<sub>node.js v18.7.0</sub>

---

c axios подобное можно провернуть так:

```
axios.get(
  url,
  {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    responseEncoding: 'binary'  
  }
)
```

Comment: Добавил после url ---> axios.get(
  url,
  {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    responseEncoding: 'binary'  
  }
)
Но все равно символ не отображается. Есть ли способ еще с применением axios или нужно все переделать на fetch?